# Visual Basic .NET Scheduling Threads

Tags: vb.net

I am having an issue where I need to implement a type of thread scheduling... I'm looking to implement a list of tasks, each with a set time that they need to execute, and after the time is up they will execute the respective code that goes with that task.  I would use a timer based solution, however, I don't think that it would be very efficient.  There will be a very large list of tasks, some of which need to be executed within seconds of being placed in the list.

To an extent, I am familiar with multithreading and expect that to be used here; I'm just looking for a starting place - someone suggested a thread pool but I'm not too sure if you can assign timers to those.

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using timers with a representative dataset to see? This is not thread scheduling in the traditional sense. I suspect the Timer is more efficient than you might think if you haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did not try that method because I assumed that it would have a very high overhead.  Furthermore, I need to have a lot of asynchronous function calls because a lot of these might be hitting at the same time - would timers only share a single thread or would they be multithreaded?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a class that inherits System.Timers.Timer.  I read that there are three types of timer classes and the one I chose is enhanced for multithreaded solutions.